# Sys admin logging in as Integration user and creating accounts. Should you see the integration user be the account owner

Tags: integration, user, service-cloud-console

If I have a sys admin logging on as an integration user and creating accounts.  Shouldn't the integration user be the account owner and not the sys admin.

Does SF look at the IP address when a user is logging in? I have a user in the sandbox who is a sys admin and he logged out and cleared his cache and logged in as a integration user but SF looks at the IP address and I wonder they see that IP address and automatically think this is the sys admin user.

Answer (score 1):

The session ID is explicitly tied to a user. By default, the owner of a record is the person who creates it. However, there are a number of reasons why the ownership could change, including triggers, workflow rules, territory assignment rules, process builders/flows, and more. In order to determine what's causing it, you'd need to turn on the debug logs (Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs) for that user and search through it for a change to the OwnerId field.